# If a matrix and its transpose both have the same eigenvectors, is it necessarily symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> If a matrix and its transpose both have the same eigenvectors, is it necessarily symmetric?

It's clear to see how if $A$ = $A^T$, they would have the same eigenvectors, but is it the only way? And how would you show it?

Comment: Your title seems different from the question you have posed. Is your question "Prove that if $A,A^T$ have the same eigenvectors then $A=A^T$" or is it "Prove that if $A=A^T$ then $A,A^T$ have the same eigenvectors".

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I meant the first one!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $A$ is a nonzero square matrix such that $A^T=-A$.

Then $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvectors, but $A$ is not symmetric.

As an example, let 
$A=\pmatrix{
0&1\\
-1&0\\
}
$.

Comment: What's an example of a matrix like that? I can't think of one

Comment: Nice, but can we find a counterexample such that all eigenvalues of $A$ are real?

Comment: @Leo: I edited in an example.

Comment: @Batominovski: I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you don't mind could I revise my question a little? Does $A^T$ have to equal either $A$ or $-A$?

Comment: @Leo: No, other relations are possible.

Comment: It turns out that, if all eigenvalues are real, then $A$ is symmetric.  I am writing a proof.

Comment: @Leo: For example, if $A+A^T=I$, then $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvectors. As a concrete example, let $A=\pmatrix{
\frac{1}{2}&1\\
-1&\frac{1}{2}\\
}$.

Answer (score 5):

> **Proposition.**  Let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.  Then, $A$ and $A^{\top}$ have the same set of $\mathbb{R}$-eigenspaces if and only if $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

**Proof.**  One direction is trivial, so we prove the more difficult direction.  Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$, with the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$, respectively.  Then, there exists a permutation $\sigma$ on the set of indices $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are eigenvectors of $A^\top$ associated to the eigenvalues $\lambda_{\sigma(1)},\lambda_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,\lambda_{\sigma(n)}$, respectively.  Thus,
$$AA^\top\,v_k=A\,(A^\top\,v_k)=A\,(\lambda_{\sigma(k)}\,v_k)=\lambda_{\sigma(k)}\,(A\,v_k)=\lambda_{\sigma(k)}\,(\lambda_k\,v_k)\,.$$
Similarly,
$$A^\top A\,v_k=A^\top\,(A\,v_k)=A^\top\,(\lambda_kv_k)=\lambda_{k}\,(A^\top\,v_k)=\lambda_{k}\,(\lambda_{\sigma(k)}\,v_k)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$AA^\top\,v_k=\lambda_k\lambda_{\sigma(k)}\,v_k=A^\top A\,v_k$$
for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.  Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is spanned by $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$, this proves that $AA^\top=A^\top A$, whence $A$ is normal.  Therefore, $A$ can be diagonalized using an orthogonal matrix.

Let now $A=Q\Lambda Q^\top$ be a diagonalization of $A$ via an orthogonal matrix $Q\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix
$\text{diag}_n\left(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\right)$.  This means $$A^\top =(Q\Lambda Q^\top)^\top=(Q^\top)^\top\Lambda^\top Q^\top =Q\Lambda Q^\top=A\,,$$
as $\Lambda^\top=\Lambda$.  Therefore, $A$ is symmetric.

> **Corollary 1.** Let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.  Then, $A$ and $A^{\top}$ have the same set of $\mathbb{C}$-eigenspaces if and only if $A$ is a normal matrix.

> **Corollary 2.** Let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be such that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.  Then, $A$ and $A^{\dagger}$ have the same set of $\mathbb{C}$-eigenspaces if and only if $A$ is a normal matrix.  Here, $(\_)^\dagger$ represents the Hermitian conjugate operator.

**Remark.**  Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and suppose that $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{K}$.  It is only known that, if $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same set of $\mathbb{K}$-eigenspaces, then $AA^\top=A^\top A$.  <s>I do not think that the converse holds for all $\mathbb{K}$.</s>  See also my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620718/which-matrices-a-in-textmat-n-times-n-mathbbk-are-orthogonally-diagona).

***Update.***  I forgot that diagonalizable matrices commute if and only if they can be simultaneously diagonalized.  Since $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{K}$, $A^\top$ is also diagonalizable over $\mathbb{K}$.  Therefore, $A$ and $A^\top$ commute (i.e., $AA^\top=A^\top A$) if and only if $A$ and $A^\top$ can be simultaneously diagonalized, which is equivalent to the condition that $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same $\mathbb{K}$-eigenspaces.  Therefore, we have the following theorem.

> **Theorem.**  Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $n$ a positive integer.  Suppose that a matrix $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{K}$.  Then, $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same $\mathbb{K}$-eigenspaces if and only if $$AA^\top=A^\top A\,.$$

Comment: Nice! (and non-trivial).

Comment: If $A=-A^T$ then $AA^T=A^TA=-A^2$, but $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Daniel  So, what is the problem?

Comment: You affirmed that if $AA^ T=A^ TA$ then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ using an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @Daniel In the proposition, it is a prerequisite that $A$ has real eigenvalues.  Did you read the part "Let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $A$ is diagonalizable $\color{red}{\text{over }\mathbb{R}}$" in the proposition statement?

Comment: Ok. I understood now. Thanks.

Comment: Great proof! 1 thing i'm a little confused about, why can you definitely conclude that $$A^TA=A^TA$$ because they have they have the same eigenvalues/eigenvectors? Matrices aren't uniquely defined by those are they?

Comment: @Leo  Let $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If two linear transformations $S$ and $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ agree at each $x_i$ (that is, $Sx_i=Tx_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$), then by linearity, $S=T$.  Apply this to $S=AA^\top$, $T=A^\top A$, and $x_i=v_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and its transpose share a common eigenbasis $\mathcal B\subset\mathbb R^n$, then $A$ must be symmetric.

By definition, for any $v\in\mathcal B$, we have $Av=\lambda v$ and $A^Tv=\mu v$ for some $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R$. Since $\langle Av,v\rangle=\langle v,A^Tv\rangle$, we get $\lambda=\mu$. Therefore $A=A^T$ on $\mathcal B$ and in turn, $A=A^T$ on $\mathbb R^n$. Hence $A$ is symmetric.